# Code contracts causing error due to potential side-effect

Tags: c#, code-contracts

I am fairly new to code contracts so i may have just done something stupid here :)

I am getting the error

> Detected expression statement evaluated for potential side-effect in
>   contracts of method '##'. (Did you mean to put the expression into a
>   Requires, Ensures, or Invariant call?)

I have the following contracts

```
Contract.Requires<ArgumentNullException>(obj != null);
Contract.Requires<ArgumentNullException>(obj.Id != null);
```

It is failing on the second contract `obj.Id != null` (`Id` is a `Guid`)

Now it is possible for `Id` to be `null` which isn't allowed in the method.  But code contracts raises the above compile error.  The method it self doesn't actually return anything so needs no ensures either.

I have removed the contract so I can compile and placed a standard `if` check.  But what is causing this?

Comment: How can a Guid be null? [Guid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.guid.aspx) is a struct! I suspect your Id property to a a string instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to mark the Id property itself as [[Pure]](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.contracts.pureattribute.aspx)

That will tell the Code Contracts Analyser that it has no side-effects.

Code Contracts don't like you calling methods that have side-effects; your code would behave differently depending on whether you had Code Contract checking enabled or not, which would be A Bad Thing.

Example:

```
public Guid Id
{
    [Pure]
    get
    {
        return _id;
    }
}
```

One further point: How can it be possible for `Id` to be null if it's a Guid? A Guid is a struct, therefore it *can't* be null. Is it possibly a nullable Guid (i.e. `Guid?`) ?

Comment: Just a confirmation here pure is meaning that Id can't be changed indirectly like from a SetId method or somthing?

Comment: When you say `[Pure]` you are telling Code Analysis that you promise that accessing the property (via the getter) does NOT change the *observable* state of the object that owns the property. You can, however, break that promise - but don't! Also note that the setter will *not* be [Pure] (of course). But it's nothing to do with whether any other calls (from this code or any other code) will change `Id`.

Comment: Yes that makes sense.  But you hit the actual problem I forgot to mark guid as a nullable type :S

Comment: Yes I will be from now on I am not using it in quite a few places

Comment: Would be nice on auto property for it to be added automatically

Comment: You can create a/change the snippet that provides you the auto property code to include the attribute, if you like.